# Trying to figure out what those bytes are

Tags: binary, hex, hexdump, ctf

I've got 6 arrays of bytes, that I'm trying to interpret.

Here they are :

- 1st array : 72B45CAA466333A5CC5AA6ADC3CF1279D1EC8
- 2nd array : 72B45CAA466336E4933314330BC656FB05418
- 3rd array : 6CBD77AB562B2AECA6DC9AC88BC496FB05448
- 4th array : 282D67BA5F2B36E498DCE4CCCBE4BA6BA5C68
- 5th array : 6CAD77AB562B365A67B3193213C59A43A4928
- 6th array : 00000000000000000000000036DB6DB6DB6D8

Each array is 255 bits, I just removed all the 0 at the end. I need to find a string of text, but I don't have anymore information about it.

I tried to convert it to ASCII, and it didn't produce anything useful.
I then tried to see if it corresponded to any file header, but again, no match.

Any idea ?

Comment: You'll need to provide more context about where this data comes from, and what you're expecting to do with it. Also, better to include all raw data verbatim and not modify it in any way (that is, include all the trailing 0's, because they may be significant, and omitting them adds unnecessary complication to decoding).

Comment: @PaulDempsey this data is from a vhd file. I am asking here because I don't know what to do with it.

If you want the raw data, here it is :
- 1st array : 72B45CAA466333A5CC5AA6ADC3CF1279D1EC8000000000000000000000000000
- 2nd array : 72B45CAA466336E4933314330BC656FB05418000000000000000000000000000
- 3rd array : 6CBD77AB562B2AECA6DC9AC88BC496FB05448000000000000000000000000000
- 4th array : 282D67BA5F2B36E498DCE4CCCBE4BA6BA5C68000000000000000000000000000
- 5th array : 6CAD77AB562B365A67B3193213C59A43A4928000000000000000000000000000

Answer (score 1):

Based on discussion in comments, this data comes from a VHD (Virtual Hard Disk file). To parse the data in a VHD, you can follow the
[Virtual Hard Disk Image Format Specification](https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=https%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2Ff%2Ff%2Fe%2Fffef50a5-07dd-4cf8-aaa3-442c0673a029%2FVirtual%2520Hard%2520Disk%2520Format%2520Spec_10_18_06.doc&wdOrigin=BROWSELINK).

Since VHDs can contain arbitrary data like any other hard drive, this data could be anything, but by decoding the VHD (or simply mounting it and reading the files on it) you'll have a head start on the task.